# Allowed memory error in getting data from db in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to get all posts from database and show the in a view. The posts that I want are stored in database with `post_type` = `product`.

I got this error:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 62918656 bytes)
```

this is my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class GetPostModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * @param $filed
     * @param $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    static function get_posts_by_filed($filed, $value)
    {
        $result = DB::table('posts')->where($filed, $value);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

this is what I do in Controller:

```
public function all_products_page(Request $request)
{

    //getting the products
    $all_products = GetPostModel::get_posts_by_filed('post_type', 'product');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($all_products);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: You need to add `->get()` after your where, or else you're just returning the QueryBuilder object instead of the actual results.

Comment: @aynber Thank you. your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because u are missing `get()`

```
public function all_products_page(Request $request)
{

//getting the products
$all_products = GetPostModel::get_posts_by_filed('post_type', 'product')->get();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($all_products);
echo '</pre>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have too many entries in your database and they all get loaded into PHP memory.

The easy solution would be to increase PHP memory limit:

`ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

The correct solution would be to try to protect your memory usage and restrain from processing all the information at once. Also, keep in mind that sending too much information to the browser might also affect performance on the client side.

A possible approach would be to use pagination. Laravel already has this integrated in the query builder:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

If passing through all the posts is absolutely necessary, you might want to chunk results as described in the Eloquent documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#chunking-results

Also, a more **Laravel** like approach would look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    /**
     * Scope a query to only include products
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeProducts($query)
    {
        return $query->where('post_type', 'product');
    }
}
```

And then, your **Controller** would look like this:

```
<?php

public function all_products_page(Request $request)
{

    Post::products()->chunk(100, function ($products) {
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            // perform action here.
        }
    });
}
```